# Declarar Variables en PLSQL

Tags: sql, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE multiplosMenores( a NUMBER, b NUMBER, numeros OUT NUMBER, contador 
OUT NUMBER) IS
BEGIN
    contador:=1;
    WHILE a<=b LOOP
      IF MOD(a,b)=0 THEN
        numeros:=a*contador;
        contador:=contador+1;
        dbms_output.put_line(numeros);  
       END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;

EXEC multiplosMenores(2,10);
```

Me salta el siguiente error:

```
PLS-00306: número o tipos de argumentos erróneos al llamar a 'MULTIPLOSMENORES'
```

Pero solo hay que ingresar dos, a y b, no el contador ni los numeros, que es el resultado final... No sé que puede estar pasando.

Answer (score 0):

Estas olvidándote de algo, los últimos 2 parámetros son definidos con 'OUT' quiere decir que son parámetros de salida, por ende debe haber una variable que reciba estos valores.

En la ejecución de tu procedimiento tienes:

```
EXEC multiplosMenores(2,10);
```

Cuando deberías tener algo como:

```
EXEC multiplosMenores(2,10, números, contador);
```

4 parámetros, 2 de entrada y 2 de salida.
Y las variables que definas que serán tus valores de salida(OUT), las podrás utilizar para presentar dicho valor.

**Nota:** Ten en cuenta en definir los valores de entrada de tu procedimiento:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE multiplosMenores( a IN NUMBER, b IN NUMBER, numeros OUT NUMBER, contador 
OUT NUMBER)
```

Comment: No sirve, PLS-00201: el identificador 'NUMEROS' se debe declarar

Comment: Claro, antes de que la pongas la variable de salida en la linea de ejecución del procedimiento, declara la variable de salida.

numeros NUMBER;
contador NUMBER;

EXEC multiplosMenores(2,10, numeros, contador);
dbms_output.putline(numeros);
dbms_output.putline(contador);